# E-mail display on mobile device

Tags: iphone, email, html-email

I am having an issue with the way an e-mail display on an iPhone.  On the desktop in Apple Mail it looks fine.  On an iPhone, the text wraps (see image attached, the top part is how it displays in apple mail on a desktop machine, the bottom is now it displays on an iPhone).  Is there a way to make the viewport adjust to display it at full-width.[image]

Comment: can you explain what it is and how you want to handle it..

Comment: please post some code

Comment: I figured it out.  I had "larger text" turned on in the accessibility settings on my iPhone.  Turning that off makes the e-mail display just fine.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, code snippet for the e-mail is below using PHPMailer and iCal support.  The HTML has inline CSS since that seems to work best for support in most e-mail clients. `<Style>` tags and stylesheets don't seem to work.  As I mentioned, having large text enabled in the accessibility settings for my iPhone was the problem.  Displays fine when I turn that off.  I guess still an issue for those with that feature turned on, but I think that is an Apple IOS issue, unless there is a way around it somehow.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->IsSendmail(); // telling the class to use SendMail transport

        try {
        $myMessage = $header."</body></html>";
        $mail->AddAddress($buyerEmailAnet, $buyerFirstName. ' '.$buyerLastName );
        $mail->AddCC('xxx');
        $mail->AddBCC('xxx');

        $mail->SetFrom('xxx', 'xxx');
        $mail->AddReplyTo('xxx', 'xxx');
        $mail->Subject = 'Los Cabos Airport Shuttles';
        $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
        $mail->MsgHTML($myMessage);   //get HTML from session
        $mail->Ical = $invite->render(false);
        //  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
        //  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
        $mail->Send();
        echo "<!--  Message Sent OK -->";

        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo "<!-- ".$e->errorMessage()." -->"; //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<!-- ".$e->getMessage()." -->"; //Boring error messages from anything else!
        }
```